# Question regarding Poisson and Geometric Distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_{i},\mathcal A _i,\mu _i)$ are probability space for $i=1,2,...n$. and $X=X_1\times X_2 \times \ldots \times X_n$. and $\mathcal A$ be smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $$\mathcal C =\{B\subset X:B=A_1\times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_n , A_i\in\mathcal A_i \}$$.Then there exist is unique probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $$ \mu \left(A_1\times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_n\right)=\mu_1(A_1)\times \mu_2( A_2) \times \ldots \times \mu_n(A_n)$$
for $A_i\in \mathcal A$. and same thing we can do for  infinite product of $X_i$'s.

> Let $(X,\mathcal A,P)$ be probability space . and  $(X^{4},\mathcal B,\mu)$ be product  probability measure . i.e $$ \mu \left(A_1\times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_4\right)=P(A_1)\times P( A_2) \times \ldots \times P(A_4)$$ For $A_i \in \mathcal A$. Let$~~E\in \mathcal A$  arbitrary and $P(E)=p$

Consider $M=\left \{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)\subset X^4 : a_i\in E  ~~\text{for exact 3 times}\right\}$ and we want to find $\mu(M)$.

Since $E \times E \times E^C\times E\subset M$ and $$\mu \left(E \times E \times E^C\times E\right)=P(E) \times P(E) \times P(E^C)\times P(E)$$$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= p\cdot p\cdot (1-p)\cdot p=(p)^3 \cdot (1-p).$$

Switching position of $E$ we have total $\binom{4}3$ different choice .and this exhaust $M$ . So we have
$$\mu (M)= \binom{4}3 \cdot (p)^3 \cdot (1-p)$$

Which is just a Binomial distribution where $E$ is success with probability $p$ . and we find probability of having 3 success in 4 independent trial.

Now  it seems  **POISSON** AND **GEOMETRIC** distribution do same but with infinite product space . which is defined [here](https://planetmath.org/infiniteproductmeasure).

Question:

> (1) : Is my above interpretation about Bionomial distribution is correct?

> (2): If it is then it is true for arbitrary probability space or we need discrete?

> (3): My guess about **POISSON** AND **GEOMETRIC** Distribution is correct ? that is in this two we are really finding probability of some **specific** event (as $E$ is here) in product space $X^{\infty}$ ?

Comment: This question seems to be concerned with finding ways to naturally "prove" the binomial distribution is "correct" in a certain context. Really the binomial/poisson/geometric distributions are defined on $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb N$ or whatever) and we find random variables that go from the generic probability space $X$ to $\Bbb R$. So I think you've shown a certain random variable is binomially distributed here, although I'm not sure how to formalise this random variable. I guess one could say, you've found a situation in which the binomial distribution naturally arises

Comment: @FShrike  I seen  the example like " given $\lambda$ average rate of car passing in one day  and find probability of 4 car passing in day ". and then they just blindly use poisson distribution .  I dont get with which sample space they are solving such a problem

Comment: Those examples use *modelling assumptions*. You cannot prove the sample space of ‘real life’ or car movements or whatever else follows a Poisson distribution, you can just justify that it’s a sensible model.