# Question About Type Of Random Variable According To Distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be probability space and $X$ is random variable on$~~\Omega$ ,with distribution $P_X$ on $(\Bbb R , B(\Bbb R)$.

**Definitions:**

> $\Rightarrow$ $X$ is said to be absolutely continuous if $P_X(A)=0$  for every Lebesgue measure zero set $A$.
>
> $\Rightarrow$  $X$ is said to be singular if $P_X(A)=1$  for some Lebesgue measure zero set $A$.
>
> $\Rightarrow$  $X$ is said to be continuous if its CDF $F_X$ is continuous function.
>
> $\Rightarrow$ $\left \{a\right\}\subset \Bbb R$ is called atom with respect to $P_X$ if $P_X \left (\left \{a\right\}\right)\gt0$.
>
> $\Rightarrow$ $X$ is continuous iff there is no atoms with respect to $P_X$.
>
> $\Rightarrow$ $X$ is said to be singular continuous if $P_X(A)=1$  for some Lebesgue measure zero set $A$ and has no atoms.
>
> $\Rightarrow$$X$ is said to be discrete if $P_X(A)=1$  for some countable set $A$.

$\Rightarrow$ Now there are 2 possibilities for $X$.

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(1)  $X$ is absolutely continuous.

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2) $\exists A$ such that Lebesgue measure of $A$ is zero but $P_X (A)\neq 0$.

$\Rightarrow$ For (2) there are two  possibilities .

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2.1)  $P_X (A)=1$  (singular).

$~~~~~~~~~~~$ (2.2)  $0<P_X (A) <1$.

$\Rightarrow$ For (2.2)  there are two  possibilities .

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2.2.1) **It has atoms**

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2.2.2) it does not have atoms .( continuous random variable).

$\Rightarrow$ For  (2.1)  there are two  possibilities .

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2.1.1) $A$ countable .($X$ is discrete).

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2.1.2) $A$ uncountable.

$\Rightarrow$ For  (2.1.2) there are two  possibilities .

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2.1.2.1) with atoms.

$~~~~~~~~~~~$(2.1.2)  **without atoms.($X$ is singular continuous)**.

**Questions:**

> $(1)$: what is type of random variable in case (2.1.2) and (2,2,1). and Is there any example of random variable with such properties?

> $(2)$: Does this exhaust all the possibilities  or I missing something ?

> $(3)$: Which is true from below ?
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~~$(1) $X$ is singular iff derivative of $F_X$ vanishes almost everywhere.
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~~$(2) $X$ is singular continuous  iff derivative of $F_X$ vanishes almost everywhere.

Comment: In 2.1 and 2.2 did you mean to write $P_X(A)$?

Comment: This analysis is a little confusing because the answer could be different depending on the choice of $A$.  For instance, suppose we have two sets $A,B$, both of Lebesgue measure zero, such that $P_X(A) = P_X(B) = 1$, but $A$ is countable and $B$ is uncountable.  Are we in case 2.1.1 or 2.1.2?

Comment: In general, you can combine these cases by forming convex combinations of measures, which correspond to mixtures of random variables.  For instance, let $\mu_1$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, $\mu_2$ a unit point mass at 0, $\mu_3$ the Cantor measure (which is atomless and assigns measure 1 to the Cantor set).  Then $\mu = \frac{1}{3} (\mu_1 + \mu_2 + \mu_3)$ is a measure of type 2.2.1, if I understand your cases correctly.

Comment: In terms of random variables, let $X_1 \sim U(0,1)$, $X_2 = 0$, and $X_3$ have the Cantor distribution.  Let $Y$ be independent of $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ and taking the values $1,2,3$ with equal probability 1/3.  Then $$X(\omega) = X_{Y(\omega)}(\omega) = \begin{cases} X_1(\omega), & Y(\omega) = 1 \\  X_2(\omega), & Y(\omega) = 2  \\  X_3(\omega), & Y(\omega) = 3 \end{cases}$$ has $P_X = \mu$ as above.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes if there is another $B$ then we cant go further.

Comment: So 2.1 is really "there exists such $A$ with $P_X(A) =1$" and 2.2 is "every such $A$ has $0 < P_X(A) < 1$"?  And similarly for 2.1.1 and 2.1.2.

Comment: @NateEldredge No  first i take there is $A$ such that $P_X (A) \neq 0$ and then two cases

Comment: But then this does not really make sense.  Let $P_X$ be Cantor measure which is supported on the Cantor set $C$, and is of course singular continuous.  In (2) we could take $A = C \cap [0,1/2]$, so $P_X(A) = 1/2$, which would seem to put us in case 2.2. Even though we "should" be in 2.1 if we had made the "correct" choice of $A=C$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I got your point .we cant decide by single of $A$ . there could be another set

Comment: @NateEldredge How you quickly defined such $X$ ?

Comment: Do you mean the $X$ in my [third comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778223/question-about-type-of-random-variable-according-to-distribution?noredirect=1#comment10154478_4778223)?  It's a standard construction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution

Comment: @NateEldredge  Please check it once . [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4776647/1189696]